# How to Use sugar orm and google analytics at one project

Tags: android, google-analytics, sugarorm

Sugar ORM requires me to set my android:name as com.orm.SugarApp to function.
How can I use other libraries that also require my android:name to be changed?

I try :

```
public class Manage extends SugarApp {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // do any thing
    }
}


<application
    android:name=".Manage"
    ...
>
```

t doesn't save any thing!
and after i remove app and test with

```
<application
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
    ...
>
```

it works but my stuf doesn't

Comment: I understand English is probably not your first language but I can't understand your question at all.

Comment: edited, please check again, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pre-Versions It shows Force Close but in current version `1.4` ican solve it easy
I made Class Extends SugarApp but Sugar Context Didn't Initialized

```
public class Manage extends SugarApp {

    // Here This Method Overrideed    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SugarContext.init(this); // Here This Method Called
        LTH.dLog("Manage_TAG", "On Create Manage Class");
    }

    // Here This Method Overrideed
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        SugarContext.terminate(); // Here This Method Called
        LTH.dLog("Manage_TAG", "On Terminate Manage Class");
    }
}
```